# Array of HashMap vs just HashMap

Tags: optimization, rust, hashmap, memoization

I am practicing on dynamic programming problems and often use a `HashMap<(usize, i32), i32>` with a key being a tuple of an index and variable for top-down (memoization). However, since all indices are eventually used in DP problems, I am wondering if it is more efficient to use an array of `HashMaps` instead.

For example, if my DP problem involves finding something in an array and the equation is `f(i, n) = f(i + 1, 0 to n)`, so all indices `i` in the range 0 to the array's length are eventually used in memoization, is it more efficient to just use `[HashMap<i32, i32>]` instead?

Comment: I don't know, and it probably depends on the actual problem and implementation, but I would imagine that the memory indirection would be worse for the performance than the lookup overhead of a single hash map.

Comment: Can't really be answered since you don't specify what kind of efficiency you want (time, memory, implementation, ...). But ultimately the only way to get meaningful answers is a benchmark.

Comment: If one isn't superior than the other, I would like to know the tradeoff (in space, time, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer will differ greatly based on the data. For example, if there's a large amount of data and it does many calls with the same index in a row, this would probably make the array of maps faster. If you have lots of data for one index, remove most of them, and then consume lots of data for another index, this would probably make the single map faster, since it avoids extra allocations.

This is also dependent on CPU and other system specs, so if you want a reliable answer, run a benchmark yourself.

However, there's many things you can do to speed up the performance of both.

- Run with `--release`, use [link-time optimization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#lto), use [profile-guided optimization](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/profile-guided-optimization.html).
- Use a faster [hasher](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hash/trait.Hash.html), such as [aHash](https://docs.rs/ahash/), or write your own that fits your data. These plug directly into the standard library hashmap.
- Try other hashmaps. The standard library one is very fast for general data, but you may find a different one is fast for your specific data.
- Don't use a hashmap. If you have reasonable bounds on the `i32` and `usize`, you can simply store elements in an array or vec with a length equal to the two ranges multiplied. Unless this is extremely large, it will most likely be faster than the hashmap, especially if there is any clustering of input data.
- Specifically for dynamic programming problems, you can often reorder your data so that you don't need memoization.